# is okay to pass jQuery element to jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I want to write a common javascript function which takes ID or jquery element as parameter

```
function common(ID_or_Element)
{
  return $(ID_or_Element).val();
}
```

1st call

```
  common("#elementID");
```

2nd call

```
$element = $("#elementID");
common($element)
```

the above code is working, but is it okay to pass jQuery element inside a jQuery selector. In 2nd call im passing jQuery element, and in turn common function will pass that to jQuery selector

Comment: Yes, its fine to pass element http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-element

Comment: Yes. it is okay. `$(selector)` is the same as `$($(selector))`

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, your common() function will correctly select the element using your provided argument: the selector "#yourid" or its corresponding jQuery element $("#yourid").

Jquery can handle both and there is no problem with passing a jQuery element inside a jQuery selector.